# How to sum many numbers inside 2D array using awk

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, awk, array

I need to sum numbers located in a file like this one:

```
       column1  column2 column3
 row1   a(1,1)   a(1,2)  a(1,3)
 row2   a(2,1)   a(2,2)  a(2,3)
 row3   a(3,1)   a(3,2)  a(3,3)
 row4   a(4,1)   a(4,2)  a(4,3)
 row5   a(5,1)   a(5,2)  a(5,3)
 row6   a(6,1)   a(6,2)  a(6,3)
 row7   a(7,1)   a(7,2)  a(7,3)
 row8   a(8,1)   a(8,2)  a(8,3)
 row9   a(9,1)   a(9,2)  a(9,3)
 row10  a(10,1)  a(10,2) a(10,3)
 row11  a(11,1)  a(11,2) a(11,3)
 row12  a(12,1)  a(12,2) a(12,3)


       column4  column5 column6
 row1  b(1,1)   b(1,2)  b(1,3)
 row2  b(2,1)   b(2,2)  b(2,3)
 row3  b(3,1)   b(3,2)  b(3,3)
 row4  b(4,1)   b(4,2)  b(4,3)
 row5  b(5,1)   b(5,2)  b(5,3)
 row6  b(6,1)   b(6,2)  b(6,3)
 row7  b(7,1)   b(7,2)  b(7,3)
 row8  b(8,1)   b(8,2)  b(8,3)
 row9  b(9,1)   b(9,2)  b(9,3)
 row10 b(10,1)  b(10,2) b(10,3)
 row11 b(11,1)  b(11,2) b(11,3)
 row12 b(12,1)  b(12,2) b(12,3)
```

the output should be like this:

```
  column1    a(1,1)+a(2,1)+a(5,1)+a(6,1)+a(7,1)+a(8,1)+a(11,1)      a(3,1)+a(4,1)+a(9,1)+a(10,1)+a(12,1)  
  column2    a(1,2)+a(2,2)+a(5,2)+a(6,2)+a(7,2)+a(8,2)+a(11,2)      a(3,2)+a(4,2)+a(9,2)+a(10,2)+a(12,2) 
  column3    a(1,3)+a(2,3)+a(5,3)+a(6,3)+a(7,3)+a(8,3)+a(11,3)      a(3,3)+a(4,3)+a(9,3)+a(10,3)+a(12,3)
  column4    b(1,1)+b(2,1)+b(5,1)+b(6,1)+b(7,1)+b(8,1)+b(11,1)      b(3,1)+b(4,1)+b(9,1)+b(10,1)+b(12,1)
  column5    b(1,2)+b(2,2)+b(5,2)+b(6,2)+b(7,2)+b(8,2)+b(11,2)      b(3,2)+b(4,2)+b(9,2)+b(10,2)+b(12,2)
  column6    b(1,3)+b(2,3)+b(5,3)+b(6,3)+b(7,3)+b(8,3)+b(11,3)      b(3,3)+b(4,3)+b(9,3)+b(10,3)+b(12,3)
```

I have a way to do something similar but which only its useful for 4 rows. I need o modify this script :

```
sed 's/row[1-9]//;/^$/d' file |    #elimina os rows
pr -2t -w 1000| 
awk 'NR==1{$1=$1; print; next} 
 !(NR%2){split($0,a); next}          
        {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i+=a[i]}1' | 
 tr ' ' '\n' | 
 pr -3t
```

Note to compute sum use

```
   $ tr -d 'ab(,)' < file > filenums
```

I think that it is necessary to do a modification in the awk section, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Please do not post minor nuances of the [SAME QUESTION](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286568/how-to-sum-numbers-inside-many-2d-arrays) as a separate question. You can easily update your original question to solicit more answers.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/37439339/4957508

Comment: please guys, see the question not is the same. I put a new question related, in a new post to because it is more challenging.

Comment: @MelBurslan Updating the original question to change what it's asking after somebody has already answered it is explicitly what we don't want people to do

Comment: I don't understand the format for the example. Why is column 1 split into `a(1,1)+a(2,1)+a(5,1)+a(6,1)+a(7,1)+a(8,1)+a(11,1) ` and `a(3,1)+a(4,1)+a(9,1)+a(10,1)+a(12,1)` instead of
 `a(1,1)+a(2,1)+a(3,1)+ ... +a(12,1)`

Comment: @John, I did not see your answer ???

Answer (score 2):

Given the irregular choices of which rows to accumulate, it's hard to device a more generic solution, and it ends up as cherry picking, like the following:

```
sed 's/row[0-9]*//;/^$/d' file | pr -2t -w 1000 | awk '
NR==1 {split($0,h);w=NF;c=".aabbaaaabbab";next;}
substr(c,NR,1)=="a" {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]+=$i;next;}
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) b[i]+=$i;}
END {for(i=1;i<=w;i++)printf"%s %d %d\n",h[i],a[i],b[i];}'
```

The final layout is then also generated directly from `awk`. Obviously the cherry picking can be done in many different ways; here I've used a string of "a" and "b" to represent which rows add into which result column.

Note that the initial `sed` expression also needed a slight revision to cater for row numbers above 9.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a literal answer to your question, using just `awk`:

```
awk '
  /column4/ { c = 3 }   # add three for the second set of columns
  /row/ {
    row = substr($1,4)  # extract the row number
    col[1+c,row] = $2   # extract column 1 or 4, store in hash
    col[2+c,row] = $3   # extract column 2 or 5, store in hash
    col[3+c,row] = $4   # extract column 3 or 6, store in hash
  }
  END {
    split("1 2 5 6 7 8 11", out1) # create an array of first set of rows
    split("3 4 9 10 12", out2)    # create an array of second set of rows

    for (c = 1; c <= 6; c++) {
      out = sprintf("  column%d    %s", c, col[c,1]) # title and first row
      for (r = 2; r <= 7; r++) {
        out = out "+" col[c,out1[r]]                 # the rest of the first set
      }
      out = out "      " col[c,3]                    # spaces, 1st row of 2nd set
      for (r = 2; r <= 5; r++) {
        out = out "+" col[c,out2[r]]                 # the rest of the 2nd set
      }
      print out
    }
  }
' file
```

This outputs:

```
  column1    a(1,1)+a(2,1)+a(5,1)+a(6,1)+a(7,1)+a(8,1)+a(11,1)      a(3,1)+a(4,1)+a(9,1)+a(10,1)+a(12,1)
  column2    a(1,2)+a(2,2)+a(5,2)+a(6,2)+a(7,2)+a(8,2)+a(11,2)      a(3,2)+a(4,2)+a(9,2)+a(10,2)+a(12,2)
  column3    a(1,3)+a(2,3)+a(5,3)+a(6,3)+a(7,3)+a(8,3)+a(11,3)      a(3,3)+a(4,3)+a(9,3)+a(10,3)+a(12,3)
  column4    b(1,1)+b(2,1)+b(5,1)+b(6,1)+b(7,1)+b(8,1)+b(11,1)      b(3,1)+b(4,1)+b(9,1)+b(10,1)+b(12,1)
  column5    b(1,2)+b(2,2)+b(5,2)+b(6,2)+b(7,2)+b(8,2)+b(11,2)      b(3,2)+b(4,2)+b(9,2)+b(10,2)+b(12,2)
  column6    b(1,3)+b(2,3)+b(5,3)+b(6,3)+b(7,3)+b(8,3)+b(11,3)      b(3,3)+b(4,3)+b(9,3)+b(10,3)+b(12,3)
```

However, you also mentioned using `tr -d 'ab(,)'` to "compute sum" and I don't know what you mean there; this command will merely remove the characters you gave, so the first set of column1's output would become `11+21+51+61+71+81+111`.  Is that what you want?  If so, wouldn't you also want to add those numbers together and print `407` in that case?

I just assumed a() and b() were functions and you'd be evaling them somewhere.  If they're not, you might as well do that all in `awk`.